# How to handle FFmpeg hardware decoder initialisation failure

Tags: c#, c, ffmpeg, autogen

I'm using the FFmpege.AutoGen library in my project and found a crash on a [video](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=55ec6f32d5e342fcbfba376ca2cc409a) using hardware decoding.
So I went back to the [example](https://github.com/Ruslan-B/FFmpeg.AutoGen/tree/master/FFmpeg.AutoGen.Example) and tested it there and found the same result.

The example reports the following

```
Current directory: D:\...\Ruslan-B\FFmpeg.AutoGen\FFmpeg.AutoGen.Example\bin\Debug\net6.0
Running in 64-bit mode.
FFmpeg binaries found in: D:\...\Ruslan-B\FFmpeg.AutoGen\FFmpeg\bin\x64
FFmpeg version info: 5.0-full_build-www.gyan.dev
Use hardware acceleration for decoding?[n]
y
Select hardware decoder:
1. AV_HWDEVICE_TYPE_CUDA
2. AV_HWDEVICE_TYPE_DXVA2
3. AV_HWDEVICE_TYPE_QSV
4. AV_HWDEVICE_TYPE_D3D11VA
5. AV_HWDEVICE_TYPE_OPENCL
6. AV_HWDEVICE_TYPE_VULKAN
Selected [2]

Decoding...
[mpegts @ 0000012917fced00] parser not found for codec klv, packets or times may be invalid.
[h264 @ 000001293b424080] Reinit context to 1920x1088, pix_fmt: yuv420p
[mpegts @ 0000012917fced00] parser not found for codec klv, packets or times may be invalid.
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 000001293b9a6940] Using D3D9Ex device.
codec name: h264
[h264 @ 000001293b8a5040] Decoder GUIDs reported as supported:
[h264 @ 000001293b8a5040] {ee27417f-5e28-4e65-beea-1d26b508adc9}[h264 @ 000001293b8a5040]  0[h264 @ 000001293b8a5040]
[h264 @ 000001293b8a5040] {bf22ad00-03ea-4690-8077-473346209b7e}[h264 @ 000001293b8a5040]  0[h264 @ 000001293b8a5040]
[h264 @ 000001293b8a5040] {e07ec519-e651-4cd6-ac84-1370cceec851}[h264 @ 000001293b8a5040]  0[h264 @ 000001293b8a5040]
[h264 @ 000001293b8a5040] {bcc5db6d-a2b6-4af0-ace4-adb1f787bc89}[h264 @ 000001293b8a5040]  0[h264 @ 000001293b8a5040]
[h264 @ 000001293b8a5040] {1b81bea4-a0c7-11d3-b984-00c04f2e73c5}[h264 @ 000001293b8a5040]  0[h264 @ 000001293b8a5040]
[h264 @ 000001293b8a5040] {1b81be68-a0c7-11d3-b984-00c04f2e73c5}[h264 @ 000001293b8a5040]  0[h264 @ 000001293b8a5040]
[h264 @ 000001293b8a5040] {d79be8da-0cf1-4c81-b82a-69a4e236f43d}[h264 @ 000001293b8a5040]  0[h264 @ 000001293b8a5040]
[h264 @ 000001293b8a5040] {f9aaccbb-c2b6-4cfc-8779-5707b1760552}[h264 @ 000001293b8a5040]  0[h264 @ 000001293b8a5040]
[h264 @ 000001293b8a5040] {705b9d82-76cf-49d6-b7e6-ac8872db013c}[h264 @ 000001293b8a5040]  0[h264 @ 000001293b8a5040]
[h264 @ 000001293b8a5040] {c528916c-c0af-4645-8cb2-372b6d4adc2a}[h264 @ 000001293b8a5040]  0[h264 @ 000001293b8a5040]
[h264 @ 000001293b8a5040] {07cfaffb-5a2e-4b99-b62a-e4ca53b6d5aa}[h264 @ 000001293b8a5040]  0[h264 @ 000001293b8a5040]
[h264 @ 000001293b8a5040] {91cd2d6e-897b-4fa1-b0d7-51dc88010e0a}[h264 @ 000001293b8a5040]  0[h264 @ 000001293b8a5040]
[h264 @ 000001293b8a5040] {90b899ea-3a62-4705-88b3-8df04b2744e7}[h264 @ 000001293b8a5040]  0[h264 @ 000001293b8a5040]
[h264 @ 000001293b8a5040] {442b942a-b4d9-4940-bc45-a882e5f919f3}[h264 @ 000001293b8a5040]  0[h264 @ 000001293b8a5040]
[h264 @ 000001293b8a5040] {8c56eb1e-2b47-466f-8d33-7dbcd63f3df2}[h264 @ 000001293b8a5040]  0[h264 @ 000001293b8a5040]
[h264 @ 000001293b8a5040] {5b11d51b-2f4c-4452-bcc3-09f2a1160cc0}[h264 @ 000001293b8a5040]  0[h264 @ 000001293b8a5040]
[h264 @ 000001293b8a5040] {75fc75f7-c589-4a07-a25b-72e03b0383b3}[h264 @ 000001293b8a5040]  0[h264 @ 000001293b8a5040]  1[h264 @ 000001293b8a5040]
[h264 @ 000001293b8a5040] {107af0e0-ef1a-4d19-aba8-67a163073d13}[h264 @ 000001293b8a5040]  0[h264 @ 000001293b8a5040]  1[h264 @ 000001293b8a5040]
[h264 @ 000001293b8a5040] {463707f8-a1d0-4585-876d-83aa6d60b89e}[h264 @ 000001293b8a5040]  0[h264 @ 000001293b8a5040]
[h264 @ 000001293b8a5040] {a4c749ef-6ecf-48aa-8448-50a7a1165ff7}[h264 @ 000001293b8a5040]  1[h264 @ 000001293b8a5040]
[h264 @ 000001293b8a5040] {76988a52-df13-419a-8e64-ffcf4a336cf5}[h264 @ 000001293b8a5040]  0[h264 @ 000001293b8a5040]
[h264 @ 000001293b8a5040] {80a3a7bd-89d8-4497-a2b8-2126af7e6eb8}[h264 @ 000001293b8a5040]  1[h264 @ 000001293b8a5040]
[h264 @ 000001293b8a5040] {a74ccae2-f466-45ae-86f5-ab8be8af8483}[h264 @ 000001293b8a5040]
[h264 @ 000001293b8a5040] {1b81be94-a0c7-11d3-b984-00c04f2e73c5}[h264 @ 000001293b8a5040]  0[h264 @ 000001293b8a5040]
[h264 @ 000001293b8a5040] {1b81bea2-a0c7-11d3-b984-00c04f2e73c5}[h264 @ 000001293b8a5040]  0[h264 @ 000001293b8a5040]
[h264 @ 000001293b8a5040] {49761bec-4b63-4349-a5ff-87ffdf088466}[h264 @ 000001293b8a5040]  0[h264 @ 000001293b8a5040]
[h264 @ 000001293b8a5040] No decoder device for codec found
[h264 @ 000001293b8a5040] Failed setup for format dxva2_vld: hwaccel initialisation returned error.
[h264 @ 000001293b8a5040] Reinit context to 1920x1088, pix_fmt: yuv420p
Fatal error. System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
   at FFmpeg.AutoGen.ffmpeg+<>c.<.cctor>b__7_466(FFmpeg.AutoGen.AVFrame*, FFmpeg.AutoGen.AVFrame*, Int32)
   at FFmpeg.AutoGen.ffmpeg.av_hwframe_transfer_data(FFmpeg.AutoGen.AVFrame*, FFmpeg.AutoGen.AVFrame*, Int32)
   at FFmpeg.AutoGen.Example.VideoStreamDecoder.TryDecodeNextFrame(FFmpeg.AutoGen.AVFrame ByRef)
   at FFmpeg.AutoGen.Example.Program.DecodeAllFramesToImages(FFmpeg.AutoGen.AVHWDeviceType)
   at FFmpeg.AutoGen.Example.Program.Main(System.String[])
```

The errors/messages

```
...
[h264 @ 0000013533bfb040] No decoder device for codec found
[h264 @ 0000013533bfb040] Failed setup for format dxva2_vld: hwaccel initialisation returned error.
[h264 @ 0000013533bfb040] Reinit context to 1920x1088, pix_fmt: yuv420p
```

are reported in the call to

```
error = ffmpeg.avcodec_receive_frame(_pCodecContext, _pFrame);
```

The result (error) of ffmpeg.avcodec_receive_frame is 0. so there's no obvious error.
But the messages make it obviously that the hardware decoder can't handle the video.

The exception is thrown in the call to `ffmpeg.av_hwframe_transfer_data()`

```
if (_pCodecContext->hw_device_ctx != null)
{
    ffmpeg.av_hwframe_transfer_data(_receivedFrame, _pFrame, 0).ThrowExceptionIfError();
    frame = *_receivedFrame;
}
```

My question is **how can I determine this beforehand and not use the hardware decoder?** i.e. fall back to the software decoder.

Edit:
I've found that `_pCodecContext->hwaccel` is null after the call to `ffmpeg.avcodec_receive_frame(_pCodecContext, _pFrame);` when for the Truck.ts video but for videos where the hardware decoder is working `_pCodecContext->hwaccel` is non-null.

Updating the code to

```
if (_pCodecContext->hw_device_ctx != null && _pCodecContext->hwaccel != null)
{
    ffmpeg.av_hwframe_transfer_data(_receivedFrame, _pFrame, 0).ThrowExceptionIfError();
    frame = *_receivedFrame;
}
```

Seems to be enough to catch the error.
**Is the right way to check that the hardware decoder is working or is there a better approach?**

Comment: If this is actually a programming question, you should tag the question with the language you're working with, and also remove emphasis on the end-user output which makes it seem like not a programming question.

Comment: Yes it's a programming question. hence the link to the [source code](https://github.com/Ruslan-B/FFmpeg.AutoGen/tree/master/FFmpeg.AutoGen.Example) and the included sections of code where the problem is raised when viewing the linked video.
I've added tags for C and C# since the C# code is an autogenerated wrapper around the C API.
But really I think a solution in most languages would point to a how to do similar in C/C#.

Comment: This is a good question. I was trying similarly to find a proper way to handle it once and not checking it on every frame. However it does not seem possible. By the way, one tip, some videos might require to allow a profile mismatch to be able to hardware decode them. However, this can cause issues for other videos. Eg;-

codecCtx->hwaccel_flags |= AV_HWACCEL_FLAG_ALLOW_PROFILE_MISMATCH;

Comment: Thanks for the tip @surgeonix. The [FFmpeg docs](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.4/group__lavc__hwaccel.html#ga7403e00bf9dc00ed3d06579611075994) kind of scare me off. "**If the stream is actually not supported then the behaviour is undefined, and may include returning entirely incorrect output while indicating success.**"

Stability is key for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must check `_pFrame->hw_frames_ctx` are not null.
If HW failed, `hw_frames_ctx` in frame will be null

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the code to use `if (_pFrame->hw_frames_ctx != null)` and this is working the same.